# I just cant seem to write this code correctly. It involves Delegates

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, delegates

So my prompt that I have to write my code for is here:
Write a program that has a class shapes. SquareArea() and RectangleArea() are the two methods that calculates the area of a square and rectangle respectively. Create a delegate named Area, invoke the methods with the help of delegates and add the results produced by both the methods. I hope that this helps.

Question:  I am getting four errors that I receive. 1) 'Sub Main' was not found in 'Module1' - I tried to fix this by adding Sub Main() after Module Module 1, but that did not fix anything. 2) 'FnAreaSquare, FnAreaRectangle, and FnAreaBoth' are not declared. In other assignments I have done, this was how we did it. I am incapable of figuring out how to fix these problems. So please, If anyone has the time, can you look over my code and point out any mistakes I may have made? Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
Module Module1

    Public Delegate Sub Area()
    Sub Delegates()
        Dim Fns As Area
        Fns = New Area(AddressOf FnAreaSquare)
        Fns()
        Fns = New Area(AddressOf FnAreaRectangle)
        Fns()
        Fns = New Area(AddressOf FnAreaBoth)
        Fns()
    End Sub

    Public Class Shapes
        Dim SqSide, RectSide1, RectSide2 As Double

        Sub FnAreaSquare()

            SqSide = 6
            Console.WriteLine("The area of the square is " & (SqSide) ^ 2)
            Console.ReadKey()

        End Sub

        Sub FnAreaRectangle()

            RectSide1 = 7
            RectSide2 = 3
            Console.WriteLine("The area of the rectangle is " & (RectSide1 * RectSide2))
            Console.ReadKey()

        End Sub

        Sub FnAreaBoth()

            Console.WriteLine("The area of the both shapes added is " & (((SqSide) ^ 2) + (RectSide1 * RectSide2)))
            Console.ReadKey()

        End Sub

    End Class



End Module
```

This question is really killing me as I have spent so much time on it. Knowing that someone who is out there who can probably help me is awesome. Thanks guys!

UPDATE: Here is my new code. I have everything going right, but I cannot figure out how to run what also goes on in the Shapes Class. I have to include the Shapes Class in my project, so I thought I would add Answer and Answer 1 together in it. If there is a better way I can Implement the Shapes Class into my program without changing the structure of the program much, that would be helpful. Thanks.

```
Module Module1
Dim SquareSide As Integer = 2
Dim RectangleLength As Integer = 2
Dim RectangleWidth As Integer = 3
Dim Answer As Integer
Dim Answer2 As Integer
Public Delegate Sub Area()

Sub Main()

    Dim Del As Area
    Del = New Area(AddressOf SquareArea)
    Del()

    Del = New Area(AddressOf RectangleArea)
    Del()

End Sub

Sub SquareArea()
    Answer = SquareSide ^ 2
    Console.WriteLine(Answer)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Sub RectangleArea()
    Answer2 = RectangleLength * RectangleWidth
    Console.WriteLine(Answer2)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Public Class Shapes

    Sub Shapes()

        Console.WriteLine(Answer + Answer2)

    End Sub


End Class

End Module
```

Comment: You've not explained the problem you've got with your code, and you've not asked a specific question (or any question at all, for that matter). This isn't a site for *Here's a copy/paste of my assignment and a dump of my code so far. Can someone finish it for me?* posts. What difficulty are you having with your code **specifically**, and what **specific question** can we answer for you?

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for your quick response. Sorry, I will be more clear. I do not know why the code is not properly working. My class is unfortunately online and vaguely covers topics. We were given this assignment but very little notes have been given to help. Can you please clarify what may be wrong with my program, so I can fix it? I would prefer if the assignment was not done for me so I can learn how to do it myself. Thanks!

Comment: No, I can't clarify what's wrong with your project, because you haven't explained what difficulty you're having. *It's not working* is not a useful problem description. How **specifically** is it **not working**? Please [edit] your post and provide the **specific details**. Explain what you expect the code to do, what it's doing instead or what it's doing wrong, and **ask a specific question**. *Why isn't it working?* is in no way specific. We're here to help, but you need to put forth the effort to clearly explain the difficulties and ask a question that can be answered.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you again for the response. I am getting four errors that I receive. 1) 'Sub Main' was not found in 'Module1' - I tried to fix this by adding Sub Main() after Module Module 1, but that did not fix anything. 2) 'FnAreaSquare, FnAreaRectangle, and FnAreaBoth' are not declared. In other assignments I have done, this was how we did it. I am incapable of figuring out how to fix these problems. So please, If you have the time, can you look over my code and point out any mistakes I may have made? Thank you.

Comment: Once again, [edit] your post and add the information there. If it's not in the question, it doesn't exist. Don't bury details in comments. Put them in the question.

Comment: Have you looked up delegates and how they work? Also should a user be inputting these values?

Comment: @KenWhite I have added the question thank you for sticking with me.

Comment: @Zaggler yes, but when I do, I find mixed results on how different people prefer to do them. I went to Visual Basic on Microsoft and it helped slightly but not significantly. Thanks!

Comment: @Zaggler no a user does not need to input the values.

Comment: @Zaggler awesome thanks! Unfortunately i am not at my computer anymore, and am using the phone app right now, but I will jump on it right in the morning!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you, I have commented it through-out so you can see what is happening. Also this will ask user for the input, if you do not need it remove it and hard code the values you want. There is only one calculate method because the signature has to match the delegate, you could create two methods and two delegates, but you don't need to. Another thing worth mentioning you could create a function that does the calculation when the properties are set to another property so you don't have to perform the calculation at the end.

```
 Module Module1

'Create instance of Shapes class
Public shape As New Shapes

'Delegate to use we are going to invoke
Delegate Sub Area(ByVal x As Shapes)

Sub Main()

    AskForInput()

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Asks user for input.
''' </summary>
Public Sub AskForInput()
    If Integer.TryParse(InputBox("Enter side size", "Square Size"), shape.SquareSide) Then
        If Integer.TryParse(InputBox("Enter rectangle length", "Rectangle Length"), shape.RectangleLength) Then
            If Integer.TryParse(InputBox("Enter rectangle width size", "Rectangle Width"), shape.RectangleWidth) Then
                'we are good to go now!

                ' Create an instance of the delegate.  
                Dim a As Area = AddressOf shape.CalculateArea

                'Call the method now.
                a.Invoke(shape)

            Else
                If MsgBox("Invalid Size", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Continue?") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                    AskForInput()
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If MsgBox("Invalid Size", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Continue?") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                AskForInput()
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If MsgBox("Invalid Size", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Continue?") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            AskForInput()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Class Shapes

    Public Property SquareSide As Integer = 0
    Public Property RectangleLength As Integer = 0
    Public Property RectangleWidth As Integer = 0

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Calculates area of a square and rectangle.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="shape"></param>
    Public Sub CalculateArea(ByVal shape As Shapes)
        Console.WriteLine("Area of the square is: " & CStr(shape.SquareSide ^ 2))
        Console.WriteLine("Area of the rectangle is: " & CStr(shape.RectangleLength * shape.RectangleWidth))

        Console.Read()
    End Sub


End Class

End Module
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The code seems to make sense to me, but I believe it has passed what we have learned so far. I have updated my code, a lot of it corrected thanks to your help, but I seem to be stuck on one issue. Please read my update section for more info. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Im not sure Im following you? Its one class which you require and the delegate you need. I mentioned if you dont require input you can remove that if you want. What is hard or as you mentioned ***passed what you have learned***.